# How to configure 'MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK' in IBM MQ Connection Factory?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm having a race condition between two threads simultaneously trying to close a JMS Session, which was created for the IBM MQ broker. It appears theres an option to prevent different threads from using a same connection handler simultaneously. The config is called 'MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK' (check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q095480_.htm). 
I'm looking for some way to configure this property using the MQConnectionFactory, in the IBM MQ Java client (v.9.1.1.0).

I've already tried using the connectionFactory.setMQConnectionOptions, and or-ing the 'com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC#MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK' constant to the actual value, but the client fails to start, telling me it's that the connection options are not valid.

```
  connectionFactory.setMQConnectionOptions(connectionFactory.getMQConnectionOptions());
    connectionFactory.setMQConnectionOptions(connectionFactory.getMQConnectionOptions() | MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK);
```

I've found in some adaptation of the IBM MQ client to GoLang that the flag is setted in here:

```
if gocno == nil {
        // Because Go programs are always threaded, and we cannot
        // tell on which thread we might get dispatched, allow handles always to
        // be shareable.
        gocno = NewMQCNO()
        gocno.Options = MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK
    } else {
        if (gocno.Options & (MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK |
            MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK)) == 0 {
            gocno.Options |= MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_NO_BLOCK
        }
    }
    copyCNOtoC(&mqcno, gocno)

    C.MQCONNX((*C.MQCHAR)(mqQMgrName), &mqcno, &qMgr.hConn, &mqcc, &mqrc)
```

Does anyone dealt with this problem, or used this flag?

EDIT - Added thread dumps from two locked threads.
I have the following threads locked:
1) JMSCCThreadPoolWoker, aka, IBM worker handling the exception raised by an IBM TCP receiver thread:

```
"JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-493": inconsistent?, holding [0x00000006d605a0b8, 0x00000006d5f6b9e8, 0x00000005c631e140]
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.util.ReentrantMutex.acquire(ReentrantMutex.java:167)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.util.ReentrantMutex.acquire(ReentrantMutex.java:73)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.requestDispatchLock(RemoteHconn.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQCTL(RemoteFAP.java:2576)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.monitoring.JmqiInterceptAdapter.MQCTL(JmqiInterceptAdapter.java:333)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerOwnerShadow.controlAsyncService(WMQConsumerOwnerShadow.java:169)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerOwnerShadow.stop(WMQConsumerOwnerShadow.java:471)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.stop(WMQSession.java:1894)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.stop(JmsSessionImpl.java:2515)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.stop(JmsSessionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.stop(JmsConnectionImpl.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.stop(MQConnection.java:473)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:361)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$AggregatedExceptionListener.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:715)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsProviderExceptionListener.run(JmsProviderExceptionListener.java:413)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)
```

2) A message handling threads, which happens to be processing a message, and in a Catch clause, attemps to close the sessions/producer/consumer (there's a JMS REPLY_TO handling situtation).

```
"[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.07: CPU_LITE @76c382e9": awaiting notification on [0x00000006d5f6b9c8], holding [0x0000000718d73900]
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:383)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:275)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.physicalClose(CachingConnectionFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.jms.commons.internal.connection.session.DefaultJmsSession.close(DefaultJmsSession.java:65)
    at org.mule.jms.commons.internal.common.JmsCommons.closeQuietly(JmsCommons.java:165)
    at org.mule.jms.commons.internal.source.JmsListener.doReply(JmsListener.java:326)
at MORE STUFF BELOW
```

Comment: What error do you get? There are a number of dead locks in recent MQ versions.

Comment: Just added locked thread dumps above. There's no specific error. The error is the deadlock.

Comment: Try 9.1.2 it has the fix for [IT27638: An MQ JMS application deadlocks after IT23101 when multiple threads compare JMS destinations](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IT27638). If that's it I'll write up a quick answer for you.

Comment: Any update? Did the suggestion resolve the issue.

Comment: Hey Josh, sory I didn't answer. I was able to consistently reproduce the issue yesterday. I think the deadlock is caused by sth. in my code, but I try updating if not. Thanks!